# Trying to debug program

Tags: c, file, debugging, segmentation-fault

You are tasked to create a program that will read in a text file and compute statistics on the contents. Your program will count the number of alphabetic characters using isalpha(), the number of digits using isdigit() and the number of punctuation using ispunct(). (Zybook module 11). Your program will provide an appropriate report to display the analysis results to the user. Your program should work with any text file and the user should be able to select the file for input. You may create a test text file for testing and development. I suggest a short paragraph with punctuation and numbers that you can easily test the values with. Your array may be a VLA or FLA array. I suggest using an array of pointers and for each line of the text file allocate an array using calloc(). You may declare a static array, so long as it will hold 100 lines of 80 characters. A line length of 80 characters will be assumed.

Ive written most of the code but am getting a couple warnings and the program terminates abruptly and gives me a segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  //Declarations
  char paragraphArray[100][80], filename[50];
    int i = 0, puncts = 0, alphas = 0, nums = 0, line = 0;

    //Ask user what file to load and assign it to filename
    printf("Enter the filename to wish to load: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    //FIle pointer is tagged
    FILE *fPoint;

    //Opens file pointer as the user-named file in read mode
    fPoint = fopen(filename, "r");

    //If file not found, a NULL value is assigned and prints to screen.
    if(fPoint == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open file");

    //Else statement that reads the file line by line starting at index i=0
    else
    {   i=0;

        while(fgets(paragraphArray[i], 80, fPoint))
        {   paragraphArray[i][(strlen(paragraphArray[i]))-1]='\0';
            i++;
        }
        //After while loop is finished, the value of i is stored as number of lines. 
        line = i;
    }

    //Closing the file
        fclose(fPoint);

    //Function Calls
    alphas = IsAlpha(paragraphArray, i);
    nums = IsDigit(paragraphArray, i);
    puncts = IsPunct(paragraphArray, i);

    //Display statistics to screen. 
    printf("There are %d alphabet characters.\n", alphas);
    printf("There are %d numerical digits.\n" , nums);
    printf("There are %d punctuation marks.\n" , puncts);
}
//Function Definitions
int IsAlpha(char paragraphArray[100][80], int line){
  int alphaCount = 0, i = 0, j = 0, asciiValue = 0;
  //Outer loop that iterates through each line of the paragraph.
  for(i = 0; i < line; i++){
    //Inner loop that compares elements of the array to ASCII values
    for(j = 0; j < 80; j++){
      asciiValue = paragraphArray[i][j];
      //if statement that does the comparison and adds to count value
      if((asciiValue <= 90 && asciiValue >= 65) || (asciiValue >= 97 && asciiValue <= 122))
        alphaCount++;
    }
  }
  //Returns count of alphabet characters after all iterations. 
  return alphaCount;
}
int IsDigit(char paragraphArray[100][80], int line){
  int digitCount = 0, i = 0, j = 0, asciiValue = 0;
  //Outer loop that iterates through each line of paragraph
  for(i = 0; i < line; i++){
    //Inner loop that compares elements of array to ASCII values.
    for(j = 0; j < 80; j++){
      asciiValue = paragraphArray[i][j];
      //If statement that does the comparison and adds count value.
      if(asciiValue >= 48 && asciiValue <= 57)
        digitCount++;
    }
  }
  //Returns count of numbers after all iterations.
  return digitCount; 
}
int IsPunct(char paragraphArray[100][80], int line){
  int punctCount = 0, i = 0, j = 0, asciiValue = 0;
  //Outer Loop that iterates through each line of paragraph.
  for(i = 0; i < line; i++){
    //Inner loop that compares elements of array to ASCII Values
    for(j = 0; j < 80; j++){
      asciiValue = paragraphArray[i][j];
      //If statement that does comparison and adds count value.
      if((asciiValue >= 33 && asciiValue <= 47) || (asciiValue >= 58 && asciiValue <= 64) || (asciiValue >= 91 && asciiValue <= 96) ||(asciiValue >= 123 && asciiValue <= 126))
      punctCount++;
    }
  }
  return punctCount;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact warning messages and describe your attempt at [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) this yourself.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then the [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger. Read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the [documentation of `<stdio.h>` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)  that you are using. `fopen` can fail, and you then should use `errno` or `perror` . `scanf` can also fail. *StackOverflow* is not a *do-my-homework* website

Comment: You could be interested by [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Read also the wikipedia about [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)). Remember that `stdout` is often line-buffered. So end your `printf` format control strings with `\n`  or use [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

Comment: You seem to have an over-complicated solution.  All you really need is a single loop, reading characters from stdin. Each character is either an alpha, numeric or punctuation.  Your assignment seem to be to use the std library functions in ctypes.h, not write your own.

Comment: I would fire the instructor.  First they require "Your program should work with any text file...", then they instruct you to use an array of 100, 80 character lines.  Complete nonsense.  This task is not properly matched to learning arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in for loop condition.
You itterate with the condition i < 80, but, if your line is lower than 80,
you compare undefined value.
Instead of 80 use strlen.

You can also use valgrind or gdp to debug your program. :)